# "git bash here" of subcontext menu opens in windows root path

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

Right clicking a folder in windows opens the submenu of a windows right click. Where you have the basic OS operations like "Open", "Edit", "rename" etc.
If git is installed you also have the option to "git bash here". This command should open the terminal/cmd and directly point to the right-clicked folder. But it's always openening in the root system folder.

tl;dr; clicking "git bash here" opens the system root folder instead of the right-clicked one

Comment: Try reporting as an issue on the git for Windows GitHub page https://github.com/git-for-windows/git

Comment: Or maybe try reinstalling git (latest version)

Comment: Do you have a `.bashrc` in your your user root? `ls -a ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks bodies!! I used to reinstall it many times but the problem hadn't solved. But Todd implies me that the .bashrc file. It still exists after I uninstall it. I delete the .bashrc and reinstall Git again. Problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve my own problem is to **uninstall Git**, and **delete .bashrc manually** (cause uninstall Git doesn't remove that file), and **install Git again**. And the terminal open correctly in my working folder rather than root system folder. Thanks to Todd.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggest, the `.bashrc` file is the one to "blame".

Deleting it would solve the issue.

However, it contains valuable declarations. So "don't throw the baby out with the bathwater": a minor edit would do the trick:

Open Git Bash window. While the bash is active, enter the following:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

In my case, the bottom line (scroll using arrows) was:

```
cd /c
```

Just delete it (press twice on <kbd>d</kbd>), and then quit with saving, by pressing <kbd>:</kbd>, and then <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That's it! The next time you open *Git Bash Here* - you should see the shell active on the relevant folder.